# Is there any lore in the Fallout universe regarding South America?

Tags: fallout-pnp-rpg

I am mastering a Fallout: Pen and Paper game, and I have an idea for a campaign we could do in the future, a campaign that would bring us to South America, specifically in the seaside Brazil area. I am trying to keep my campaigns as canon as possible, is there any official lore in the Fallout universe that can help me set up my campaign?

Comment: @mxyzplk Arqade is super down on lore questions that are about material not actually in a game. The Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE is probably the only place for this, if anywhere.

Comment: This can go here; theoretically. It may be about a video game, but I've seen some people use the SPECIAL system for tabletop play that is just as legitimate.

Of course, the unfortunate truth is that we really don't know what happened, but that's just my inner-Fallout fan speaking.

As far as lore sources go, a lot of video games can legitimately serve as lore sources for a tabletop game (though this doesn't justify asking them here), but in particular games sometimes release developer "bibles" or such that contain lore dumps but are obscure. Since Fallout has a tabletop presence, I like this.

Comment: Fallout does have quite a number of Pen and Paper players out there (even if there's no official PnP RPG, people love to run homebrew games in the Fallout universe.) I think this Q definitely has a place here on rpg.SE.

Comment: Is the PnP history based, exclusively, on the video game? That is, does the system itself have lore all it's own, or is it a direct port from the game? That'd be the deciding factor for me if this should reopen or not. Voting to hold in the meantime.

Comment: The request for "official lore from the Fallout universe" keeps this firmly in video game territory. Sorry, same answer to "Tell me about the history of Helm's Deep" or anything else from another source - not on topic here.

Comment: Agree, development documents are part of the videogame, not separate and there is no official source material beyond whats related to the videogames. Also as a sort of answer: Fallout deals with the fears and dreams of 1950's America as both a social commentary and a parody. For this reason its completely focused on America and the alternate American history that occurs. You won't have a lot of the iconic fallout items in a place like SA (vaults, power armor, the political factions from fallout games) and SA probably dodged out on most of the nuclear war.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, South America was never mentioned in the Fallout universe. From the discussion on the [Fallout wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forum%3aRest_of_the_World):

> I'm pretty sure Fallout has said nothing about South America, and as far as we know, none of their countries were in a major war.

However, on [another page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Talk%3aFallout_world), in response to "What happened to South America in Fallout?":

> I don't think that's been answered, although I personally assumed that the nuclear war was a worldwide thing, and that no country got through it intact. *(edited for grammar and spelling)*

Generally, the best thing to do in these situations is decide on something that makes sense. If you are the GM, you have a couple options: You can either do this by yourself, or with the party. I generally advise deciding on this with the party; you can all come to a group decision about how the lore and story went in South America. That way, everyone's on the same page, and everyone will find the decision reasonable. Plus, it's hard to make plot holes with a dozen eyes looking it over. However, it's definitely still possible to do by oneself.